# How to save my output results to .txt then send it as email attachment

Tags: powershell, csv, email, text, output

im newbie in powershell but happy to explore it. I have some question currently i got sample scripts that count number of rows to a target csv file but my next job would be save it to a file either CSV or text file then send it as email attachment

I have here my 1st part which is counting rows of csv

```
    $fileEntries = [IO.Directory]::GetFiles("\\servername\folder\folder2"); 
   foreach($fileName in $fileEntries) 
{ 
 $count = 0
 $filedate = (Get-Date).Date
 $reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader $filename
 while($reader.ReadLine() -ne $null){$count++}
    $reader.close()
   #Get-Content $filename | %{$lines++}
  [Console]::Writeline($filename+" "+$count+" ");  


 }
```

Comment: Can you provide commands you have tried to save and email? Is there someplace you are getting hung up? You're more likely to get assistance if you can show what you have tried and give us a specific problem to help fix.

Comment: Try `Export-CSV` or `Out-File` if you want to save your data in a CSV or TXT file. If you want to send emails, maybe this blog may help you. https://blog.mailtrap.io/powershell-send-email/

Comment: how large is the file you are line-counting? the methods you are using are normally used for _extremely large_ files, so i wonder why you are using such methods.